# Jupyter lab IFrame in Flask web page

Tags: python, iframe, flask, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I want to see the running Jupyter(http://localhost:8888) in the Flask(http://127.0.0.1:5000).

I'm basically follow up these link.
[Render a Jupyter Notebook Iframe in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008765/render-a-jupyter-notebook-iframe-in-flask/44035252#44035252)

But These error message in Chrome console logs. And nothing shows up, just white screen.

`Refused to display 'http://localhost:8888/lab?' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' 'self'".`

How can I control Jupyter Lab through Flask app?

---

My codes

main.py

```
@app.route("/")
def jupyter():
    src = "http://localhost:8888/lab?"
    return render_template("iframe.html", iframe=src)
```

iframe.html

```
<iframe frameborder='0' noresize='noresize' sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-scripts" style='position: absolute; background: transparent; width: 100%; height:100%;' src="{{ iframe }}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

jupyter_notebook_config.py

```
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*' #Basic permission
c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = True #Otherwise Jupyter restricts you modifying the Iframed Notebook
c.NotebookApp.token = '' #In my case I didn't want to deal with security
c.NotebookApp.trust_xheaders = True #May or may not make a difference to you

c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {
    'headers': {
        'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self' http://127.0.0.1:5000/ http://127.0.0.1:5000/*",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It solved ssl certificate`.

Reference : https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#using-ssl-for-encrypted-communication